# Can I change the app icon and name after app installation in Flutter for an Android app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dynamic, icons

My requirement is to change the app icon and app name dynamically after installation. I tried to use the *[flutter_dynamic_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon)* package, but I am not able to change the Android app icon and name.

Comment: try used this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Answer (score 0):

The app's name and icon are stated in the manifest and cannot be changed during runtime because Android does not permit this.

However, try change the title of the app in the title bar via `setTitle(name)`;.